# Why does L'Hôpital's rule work?

Tags: calculus

Can anyone tell me why the L'Hôpital's rule works for evaluating limits of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ and $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ ?

What I understand about limits is that when you divide a *really* small thing (that is $\rightarrow0$) by another really small thing, we get a finite value which may not be so small.

So how does differentiating the numerator and denominator help us get the Limit of a function?

Comment: This question serves a great deal for undergraduate students who get the same doubt when they are reading the principle.

Comment: It's to determine which side of the fraction is progressing to infinity or zero 'faster'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer given by Mr. Jackson Walters gives a proof why it works, but if you are looking for an answer that should give an intuition, see this :

---

> Consider the curve in the plane whose $x$-coordinate is given by $g(t)$ and whose $y$-coordinate is given by $f(t)$, i.e. $$\large t\mapsto [g(t),f(t)]. $$ Suppose $f(c) = g(c) = 0$. The limit of the ratio $\large \frac {f(t)}{g(t)}$ as $t \mapsto c$ is the slope of tangent to the curve at the point $[0, 0]$. The tangent to the curve at the point $t$ is given by $[g'(t), f'(t)]$. l'Hôpital's rule then states that the slope of the tangent at $0$ is the limit of the slopes of tangents at the points approaching zero.

---

Points to assume (credits : Thanks to Hans lundmark for pointing out what I missed and to Srivatsan for improving my formatting . )

Assume that functions $f$ and $g$ have a well defined Taylor expansion at $a$.

*Proof:*

Another way you can think of this is to use the idea of derivative: a function
$f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=a$ if $f(x)$ is very close to its tangent 
line $y = f'(a) \cdot (x-a) + f(a)$ near $x = a$. Specifically,

$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a) \cdot (x-a) + E_{1}(x)$$

where $E_{1}(x)$ is an error term which goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $a$. In fact, 
$E_{1}(x)$ must approach $0$ so fast that

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{E_1(x)}{x-a}=0$$

because $\dfrac{E_{{1}(x)}}{x-a} = \dfrac{ f(x)-f(a) }{x-a} - f'(a)  $

and we know from the definition of derivative that this quantity has 
the limit $0$ at $a$.

Similarly, if $g$ is differentiable at $x = a$,

$$g(x) = g(a) + g'(a) \cdot (x-a) + E_{2}(x)$$

where $E_{2}(x)$ is another error term which goes to $0$ as $x \to a$. If you're 
computing the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$ as $x \to a$ and if $g(a)$ is not equal to 
$0$, then as $x \to a$, the numerator becomes indistinguishable from $f(a)$ 
and the denominator from $g(a)$, so the limit is

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(a)}{g(a)} .$$

If both $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ are $0$, then we must use the tangent 
approximations to say that

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f(a) + f'(a) \cdot (x-a) + E_{1}(x)  }{ g(a) + g'(a) \cdot (x-a) + E_{2}(x) }$$

$$=\frac{f'(a) \cdot (x-a) + E_{1}(x)}{g'(a) \cdot (x-a) + E_{2}(x) }$$

$$ =\frac{f'(a) + [E_{1}(x)/(x-a)]  }{g'(a) + [E_{2}(x)/(x-a)]}$$

and we have seen that the second term becomes negligible as $x\mapsto a$.

In other words, when both function values approach $0$ as $x\mapsto a$, the 
ratio of the function values just reduces to the ratio of the slopes 
of the tangents, because both functions are very close to their 
tangent lines.

I hope you understood. Thanks a lot. Iyengar.

Comment: Same comment here as for Jackson's answer: This assumes that $f$ and $g$ have Taylor expansions at $a$, which is a stronger assumption than necessary. (But of course it's still a good argument for giving a bit of intuition.)

Comment: Do you want a complete argument ?, ok let me post it @HansLundmark

Comment: You don't have to post it for my sake (I know it already). But perhaps it would be better if the assumptions were clearly stated in the answer.

Comment: Where is the Taylor series assumption being used?

Answer (score 44):

This is far from rigorous, but the way I like to *think about* L'Hospital's Rule is this:

If I have a fraction whose numerator and denominator are both going to, say, infinity, then I can't say much about the limit of the fraction. The limit could be anything.

It's possible, though, that the numerator goes *slowly* to infinity and the denominator goes *quickly* to infinity. That would be good information to know, because then I would know that the denominator's behavior is the one that really swings the limit of the fraction overall.

So, how can I get information about the *rate of change* of a function? This is precisely the kind of thing a derivative can tell you. Thus, instead of comparing the numerator and denominator directly, I can compare the *rate of change* (i.e. the derivative) of the numerator to the *rate of change* (i.e. the derivative) of the denominator to determine the limit of the fraction overall. This is L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it in a language that normal people can understand.

Comment: @Dimme You're welcome, but what I've written is not an explanation, per se. At best, I've indicated why L'Hospital's Rule *ought* to work. The more thorough answers in this thread prove that it *does* work.

Comment: Understanding the problem is half the solution.

Comment: This is exactly the way I like to think about L'Hospital's rule! +1

Comment: Perfection, thanks

Comment: Then why do we get finite answer in some questions. limit x->0 Sinx/x = 1. Can you please explain why we get answer 1 in this question?

Comment: @darshan Take a look at their [graphs](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7By+%3D+sinx%2C+y+%3D+x%7D%2C+x+from+0+to+0.1). The functions $y = \sin x$ and $y = x$ are basically identical when $x$ is very small. (A Taylor series expansion of $\sin x$ would reveal the reason why.) In the language of my answer, L'Hospital would tell you that the rates of change of these two functions become more and more similar as $x$ approaches 0.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now.

Answer (score 19):

For the case $\frac{0}{0}$, we need only to use definition of a derivative in terms of the difference quotient. Suppose $f,g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(a)=g(a)=0$, $f$ and $g$ are continuously differentiable, and $g'(a) \ne 0$, then

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} &=& \lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-0}{g(x)-0} \\
&=&\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\\
&=&\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}}{\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}}\\
&=&\frac{\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}}{\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}}\\
&=&\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)} \end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Way better than the accepted answer!

Answer (score 4):

(http://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/~jy2wong/jenerated/blog/2012-10-07.lhopitals_rule.html) is interesting.

> At the heart of it though, L'Hopital's rule just seems to be a marriage of the ideas that differentiable functions are pretty darn close to their linear approximations at some point as long as you don't stray too far from that point and that for a continuous function, a small movement in the domain means a small movement in the value of the function.