# What is the "geometrical" intuition behind L'Hospital's rule?

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis

Is there a "geometrical" intuition behind L'Hospital's rule?
I have recently found out the "geometrical" meaning of Taylor's approximation series and I was wondering if there is something analogous for L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98082/, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584889